# Problem binding Devexpress DXRibbon RibbonPage IsEnable property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, devexpress

I know this can be a bug not yet reported by Devexpress, but is there anyone who can help me with a workaround?

My Ribbon page in Xaml is as following:

```
...
<dxr:RibbonPage Name="Home" Caption="Home"  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=IsChecked}">
...
```

I'm using Devexpress 2011 v1.4
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the IsVisible property instead of IsEnabled.  The latter one is not currently supported and you see it just because it comes from the ancestor class.

Comment: Whould it be fixed? Is there any plan for that?

Comment: We are planning to implement this feature in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is checkBox1 a standard checkbox?  I'm pretty sure the Path you want is "Checked" (not "IsChecked").

Comment: As far as i know in WPF "Checked" is an event and "IsChecked" is a property. in XAML we can only bind to a property.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  In Silverlight the property is Checked and the event is CheckedChanged.